# Keyboard only working properly, if plugged in AFTER bootup?

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot-issues, keyboard, input-device

If i plug my little keypad into my raspberry pi model 3+ and turn it on, it will boot and for a few seconds and a couple of key strokes it works... And then stops. It still shows in LSUSB but won't output any input.

However for some reason if I unplug it, power it up and wait until it reaches the end up the boot process to where I have a command prompt, and then plug it in... It works just fine.

It does not have this issue on my Ubuntu laptop. So I am assuming it's something going wrong during rasbian boot? :s I am running raspbian stretch, kernel 4.19.58-v7+